# Pyserial is obtaining inconsistent data from arduino

Tags: python, arduino, python-3.5, pyserial

I am trying to write a code for a sensor to be read by an arduino and then send that data to python in order for it to be printed and saved for future analysis. The problem is that when I look at the serial monitor of the arduino it is a consistent stream of numbers. This is what I want, however when it gets to python it results in occasionally multiplying this number by 100. This happens about every 4 lines of data. I am having trouble trying to figure out why this is happening based on the code that I have written and the codes I have used as guidelines.

**Arduino**

```
#include <HX711_ADC.h>
#include "CytronMotorDriver.h"


// Configure the motor driver.
CytronMD motor(PWM_DIR, 3, 2);  // PWM = Pin 3, DIR = Pin 2.

int up = HIGH;
int down = LOW;
int dstate = up;
float interval = 12000;
float pretime= 0;
float curtime = 0; 


// LOAD CELL
//HX711 constructor (dout pin, sck pin)
HX711_ADC LoadCell(11, 12);
float force;  
float calforce;
float newtons;


// The setup routine runs once when you press reset.
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 LoadCell.begin();
 LoadCell.start(2000); // tare preciscion can be improved by adding a few seconds of stabilising time
 LoadCell.setCalFactor(100); // user set calibration factor (float)
}

// The loop routine runs over and over again forever.
void loop() {

  LoadCell.update();
  force = LoadCell.getData();
  force = (force/285); // Force in (N) // 285 is conversion factor
  calforce = (-1.0389*force)+0.0181, // This is in lbs
  newtons = 4.45*calforce;



  //receive from serial terminal for tare
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  char inByte = Serial.read();
  if (inByte == 't') LoadCell.tareNoDelay();
  }

unsigned long curtime = millis();

  if (dstate == up && (curtime - pretime >= interval)) {
    motor.setSpeed(255);  // Run forward at full speed.
    pretime = curtime; 
    dstate = down;


  }

  if (dstate == down && (curtime - pretime >= interval)) {
    motor.setSpeed(-255);  // Run backward at full speed.
    pretime = curtime;
    dstate = up;

  }


  Serial.println(newtons);
}
```

**Arduino Output**
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08
0.08

**Python**

```
import serial
import csv
import time
from time import localtime, strftime
#import numpy as np
import warnings
import serial.tools.list_ports


__author__ = 'Matt Munn'
arduino_ports = [
    p.device
    for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if 'Arduino' in p.description
]
if not arduino_ports:
    raise IOError("No Arduino found - is it plugged in? If so, restart computer.")
if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
    warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')

Arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0],9600)

Arduino.flush()
Arduino.reset_input_buffer()

start_time=time.time()

Force = []

outputFileName = "Cycle_Pull_Test_#.csv"
outputFileName = outputFileName.replace("#", strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H %M %S", localtime()))

with open(outputFileName, 'w',newline='') as outfile:

    outfileWrite = csv.writer(outfile)

    while True:
        while (Arduino.inWaiting()==0):
            pass
        try:
            data = Arduino.readline()
            dataarray = data.decode().rstrip().split(',')
            Arduino.reset_input_buffer()
            Force = round(float(dataarray[0]),3)
            print (Force)
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit,IndexError,ValueError):
            pass

        outfileWrite.writerow([Force,"N"])
```

**Python Output**
0.08 
8.0 
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08
8.0 
0.08

This is just the bare bones of my code, I intend to control an linear actuator based on what the sensor reading is, but if I can not get this data stream to be consistent, then I can't continue the project.
Thank you!

Comment: Examples of the correct and incorrect serial data would make this a much clearer question.  I suspect the problem is the `Arduino.reset_input_buffer()` in your loop - the only thing that can possibly accomplish is throwing away valid data, although that seems more likely to produce too-small results rather than too-large.

Comment: When it is running the data stream is something like 0.08 0.08 8 0.08 0.08 0.08 8, this is an example of the output that I tend to get. Ideally I would want it to be just a stream of 0.08 or what ever number value the arduino is reading.

Comment: Looks like the `reset_input_buffer()` is chopping off the first three characters of the following reading.

Comment: I removed that based on your recommendation, and nothing seems to have changed with my data readout.

Comment: I removed the `flush() ` line and now it seems to be working for now.